# Navbar width reduces more than needed when reducing screen size below 300px using Google Chrome devtools in mobile mode

Tags: html, css, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, width

I have this issue in my webpage: when I resize the screen size to approximately below 300px, when using Google Chrome devtools "toggle device toolbar" in mobile mode, my `navbar` `width` reduces a lot and does not include its links any more.

I have tried giving my `navbar` `width: 100vw` or `100%`, and I have tried to apply this also to the `body` element, and that seems to have the same behavior when on small mobile screens.

I have tried also to set in the `head` element `maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no`, but `user-scalable no` gives problems on the `navbar`.

I haven't found anything useful online and I am pretty new to webDev. Can you please help me?

I attach a link to a screenshot (in GitHub wiki) with [an image of my problem](https://github.com/camilla-devasini/issue-with-mobile-width-when-reducing-screen/wiki)

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.body-trade-page {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(139.73deg, rgb(229, 253, 255) 0%, rgb(243, 239, 255) 100%) no-repeat fixed;
}

.trade-navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 42px;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.trade-navbar div>a {
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(122, 110, 170);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>document</title>
</head>

<body class="body-trade-page">
  <!--menu-->
  <nav class="trade-navbar">
    <div class="trade-item">
      <div class="trade-link"><a class="link-highlighted" href="/swap">Swap</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trade-item">
      <div class="trade-link"><a href="/limit">Limit</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trade-item">
      <div class="trade-link"><a href="/liquidity">Liquidity</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trade-item">
      <div class="trade-link"><a href="/perpetual">Perpetual</a></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
min-width: fit-content;
```

If you add the code above to your css class '.trade-navbar' it will force your navbar to fit all of the elements within it, no matter the size of the window.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.body-trade-page {
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(139.73deg, rgb(229, 253, 255) 0%, rgb(243, 239, 255) 100%) no-repeat fixed;
}

.trade-navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100vw;
    min-width: fit-content; /* <-- this one! */
    height: 42px;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 12px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.trade-navbar div > a {
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(122, 110, 170);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>document</title>


</head>

<body class="body-trade-page">

        <!--menu-->
        <nav class="trade-navbar">
            <div class="trade-item">
                <div class="trade-link"><a class="link-highlighted" href="/swap">Swap</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="trade-item">
                <div class="trade-link"><a href="/limit">Limit</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="trade-item">
                <div class="trade-link"><a href="/liquidity">Liquidity</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="trade-item">
                <div class="trade-link"><a href="/perpetual">Perpetual</a></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked and I have learned a new thing :)

Comment: @Camilla_dev  No problem, since this solution helped, would you help others find it by marking it as accepted (the check mark) :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go a step further from the other answer and force the nav bar to be full width no matter the screen size.

So add in a `min-width: 100vw;` in your '.trade-navbar'

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.body-trade-page {
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(139.73deg, rgb(229, 253, 255) 0%, rgb(243, 239, 255) 100%) no-repeat fixed;
}

.trade-navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100vw;
    min-width:100vw; //////Add This
    height: 42px;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 12px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.trade-navbar div > a {
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(122, 110, 170);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>document</title>


</head>

<body class="body-trade-page">

        <!--menu-->
        <nav class="trade-navbar">
            <div class="trade-item">
                <div class="trade-link"><a class="link-highlighted" href="/swap">Swap</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="trade-item">
                <div class="trade-link"><a href="/limit">Limit</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="trade-item">
                <div class="trade-link"><a href="/liquidity">Liquidity</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="trade-item">
                <div class="trade-link"><a href="/perpetual">Perpetual</a></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

This just makes sure that no matter the screen size it will always be full width.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked too. I will choose  min-width: fit-content; but I think that It is super useful as well.